# dplyr::group_by leaves variables ungrouped

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a database (`user_reg`) containing customers' information (`customer_id`), their registration date (`reg_date2`) and the date of their orders (`order_date2`; often > 1 per customer).

I want to know 
1) when the first order took place and then 
2) end up with a `tbl` with unique `user_id`, `reg_date2` and `first_order`.

After executing the code below

```
  user_reg %>% select(user_id, reg_date2, order_date2) %>% 
  group_by(user_id) %>% 
  mutate(first_order=min(order_date2)) %>%
  select(user_id, reg_date2, first_order) %>%
  arrange(user_id) %>%
  group_by(user_id)
```

I still get multiple rows per `user_id`.

```
user_id  reg_date2 first_order
     <int>     <date>      <date>
1       -1 2015-11-03  2015-11-25
2        1 2013-10-24  2014-10-11
3        1 2013-10-24  2014-10-11
4        1 2013-10-24  2014-10-11
5        1 2013-10-24  2014-10-11
6        1 2013-10-24  2014-10-11
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `summarize` instead of `mutate`?

Comment: my goal is to have a table with all the mentioned variables, summarise() will only give me user_id and first_order. Besides, even if I try to create multiple data frames, each with user_id and a variable of interest and then join them together, I still end up with multiple entries per user_id

Comment: Well, `mutate` is always going to return the same number of rows as the original dataset.  In this simple case, it'd be straightforward to keep your additional column by including `reg_date2` as a grouping variable or including it in `summarize` (e.g., `reg_date2 = unique(reg_date2`).  If you prefer `mutate`, then you'll need something like `distinct` after.

Comment: @aosmith, you could post an answer (unless you want to continue to follow the commendable "teach someone to fish" strategy you're taking ...)

Comment: brilliant, distinct(x, .keep_all=TRUE) did exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mutate` function adds variables to the existing dataset, so you will always end up with the same number of rows you started with.

You can add the `distinct` function to retain only a single unique row per id.  To keep all the other variables you'll need the `.keep_all` argument.

```
... %>%
    group_by(user_id) %>% 
    mutate(first_order = min(order_date2)) %>%
    distinct(first_order, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Going from many rows to a single row per id is often a for `summarise`, although this will drop the other variables.  If the real use case is this simple, the additional variable can be included as a grouping variable as `reg_date2` seems to be unique per `user_id`.

```
... %>%
    group_by(user_id, reg_date2) %>% 
    summarise(first_order = min(order_date2))
```

Alternatively (but with more typing), keeping `reg_date2` could be done by including it in `summarise`:

```
... %>%
group_by(user_id) %>% 
    summarise(reg_date2 = unique(reg_date2), 
              first_order = min(order_date2))
```